# What is the difference between the description and abstract meta tags?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description

There are two meta tags that seem very similar: description and abstract. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the definition of `abstract`.

For **HTML5**, [`abstract` is not registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names). So you must not use this metadata name in (X)HTML5 documents. The metadata name [`description` is defined in the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#meta-description) itself, so it’s valid to use it in (X)HTML5 documents.

In **HTML 4.01**, you can use any metadata names, so using `abstract` would be allowed. But it [should](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4) be defined in a [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751352/1591669):

> This specification does not define a set of legal meta data properties. The meaning of a property and the set of legal values for that property should be defined in a reference lexicon called a profile.

Metadata can only be useful if it’s use/scope is defined (e.g. in specifications) resp. documented (e.g. by metadata consumers).

Answer (score 4):

Another answer could be which meta tags are recognised by search engines. For example, *abstract* is not understood by Google as a valid meta tag whereas *description* is. Other search engines may have different criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One answer that I found is that the abstract is short (one sentence) while the description is longer.